# How to use keyboard keys to trigger controls in Visual Basic 2017?

Tags: vb.net

I need this information for an upcoming competition.

It took me a long time to research and make my select case code error free, but I have done it, and it just won't work. I'm attaching a screenshot. Please have a look.

[image: this is the image]

Comment: See the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page on ways to improve your question.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Post it as text in your question and format as code. How do you know what is happening when you Hide the form?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change
    Select Case Keys.KeyCode
To
    Select Case e.KeyCode
To evaluate which key was pressed (parameter e).

Comment: just tried this... it still isn't working. thanks for the help though.